# How can I construct a sentence that contains reference to the past?

Tags: past-tense

I want to construct a sentence in which I talk about the past. But my friend said that the following sentence has some grammar errors since I cannot follow **considering my interest** with a past tense. I will appreciate any help. The sentence that I have constructed is:

> Considering my interest, attending a private teaching institution that emphasizes communication skills seemed like a great chance for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sentence sounds fine to me. I never heard this rule about not using "considering [noun], ..." with a past tense verb.

Is this rule supposed to apply to the "considering ...," phrase wherever it occurs, or only when it is at the beginning of the sentence?

If you look up "considering" in [the MacMillan on-line dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/considering), you will see three examples that appear (to me) to go against the rule your friend describes:

> They’ve made remarkable progress, considering they only started last
>   week.
>
> Considering the price we paid, it was a very disappointing meal.
>
> Robert played extremely well, considering how badly injured he was.